# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to write some tests for a Flask Python Web App, to test for the Number of records in database tables, whether some pages are accessible without login, some pages are inaccessible without login and redirect to the login page; and the return for errorpages. However when I run "python tests.py" all I get is this ValueError:

```
C:\Users\User\Envs\the-dream-team\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:794: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
C:\Users\User\Envs\the-dream-team\lib\site-packages\wtforms\ext\sqlalchemy\__init__.py:9: DeprecationWarning: wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, and will be removed in WTForms 3.0. The package has been extracted to a separate package wtforms_sqlalchemy: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms-sqlalchemy .
Or alternately, check out the WTForms-Alchemy package which provides declarative mapping and more: https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy
  DeprecationWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 161, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 256, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\the-dream-team\lib\site-packages\flask_testing\utils.py", line 131, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\the-dream-team\lib\site-packages\flask_testing\utils.py", line 144, in _pre_setup
    self.app = self.create_app()
  File "tests.py", line 15, in create_app
    'mysql://mn_admin:mn2018@localhost/dreamteam_test'
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

And here is the tests.py code. What could I be doing wrong?

```
import unittest
import os
from flask import abort, url_for
from flask_testing import TestCase
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import Department, Employee, Role

class TestBase(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        # pass in test configurations
        config_name = 'testing'
        app = create_app(config_name)
        app.config.update(
            'mysql://mn_admin:mn2018@localhost/dreamteam_test'
        )
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        """ Will be called before every test """
        db.create_all()
        # create test admin user
        admin = Employee(username="admin", password="admin2018", is_admin=True)
        # create test non-admin user
        employee = Employee(username="test_user", password="test2018")
        # save users to database
        db.session.add(admin)
        db.session.add(employee)
        db.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        """ Will be called after every test """
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()


class TestModels(TestBase):

    def test_employee_model(self):
        """ Test number of records in Employee table """
        self.assertEqual(Employee.query.count(), 2)

    def test_department_model(self):
        """ Test number of records in Department table """
        # create test department
        department = Department(name="IT", description="The IT Department")
        # save department to database
        db.session.add(department)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEqual(Department.query.count(), 1)

    def test_role_model(self):
        """ Test number of records in Role table """
        # create test role
        role = Role(name="CEO", description="Run the whole company")
        # save role to database
        db.session.add(role)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertEqual(Role.query.count(), 1)

class TestViews(TestBase):

    def test_homepage_view(self):
        """ Test that homepage is accessible without login """
        response = self.client.get(url_for('home.homepage'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_login_view(self):
        """ Test that login page is accessible without login """
        response = self.client.get(url_for('auth.login'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_logout_view(self):
        """ Test that logout link is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to logout
        """
        target_url = url_for('auth.logout')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

    def test_dashboard_view(self):
        """ Test that dashboard is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to dashboard
        """
        target_url = url_for('home.dashboard')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

    def test_admin_dashboard_view(self):
        """ Test that dashboard is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to dashboard
        """
        target_url = url_for('home.admin_dashboard')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

    def test_departments_view(self):
        """ Test that departments page is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to departments page
        """
        target_url = url_for('admin.list_departments')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

    def test_roles_view(self):
        """ Test that roles page is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to roles page
        """
        target_url = url_for('admin.list_roles')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

    def test_employees_view(self):
        """ Test that employees page is inaccessible without login
            and redirects to login page then to employees page
        """
        target_url = url_for('admin.list_employees')
        redirect_url = url_for('auth.login', next=target_url)
        response = self.client.get(target_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, redirect_url)

class TestErrorPages(TestBase):

    def test_403_forbidden(self):
        # create route to abort the request with the 403 Error
        @self.app.route('/403')
        def forbidden_error():
            abort(403)

        response = self.client.get('/403')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
        self.assertTrue("403 Error" in response.data)

    def test_404_not_found(self):
        response = self.client.get('/nothinghere')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
        self.assertTrue("404 Error" in response.data)

    def test_500_internal_server_error(self):
        # create route to abort the request with the 500 Error
        @self.app.route('/500')
        def internal_server_error():
            abort(500)

        response = self.client.get('/500')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
        self.assertTrue("500 Error" in response.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You didn't need to post all those tests, when the traceback shows you that the error is happening in `create_app`.

Answer (score 2):

Given you error message, it is coming from

```
app.config.update('mysql://mn_admin:mn2018@localhost/dreamteam_test')
```

not knowing what `app` is I can at least assume from the error output that app.config is a dictionary. But when you want to call update, you need to provide a key **and** a value. I am guessing you are missing the name of the field in `app.config` that you want to update:

```
app.config.update({field_name: 'mysql://mn_admin:mn2018@localhost/dreamteam_test'})
```